# Windows Phone 8 Connection Handler / Internet Availability

Tags: windows-phone-8

My team is working on a team project aplication.  At the moment, we need an event handler to check the connection status (if it's on/off).

I had big hopes in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` Namespace, but unfortunately most important things aren't supported in wp8.

Can anyone help me with it a bit?

Edit 1#

It seems, I didn't specifed my problem well.
I'm using Mvvm light expresion, and it does not support that namespace or at least I can't add it.

I'm a newbie in using VS and c# atm, mayby I'm doing someting wrong, but simply when im trying to add the refernce to my project it does not list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I haven't tried the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace on WP8. But the new WP8 Windows.Networking.Connectivity Windows Phone Runtime namespace works just fine.

Use Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged to know when network conditions change and use Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface properties or Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation properties to see what's up.

```
    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintNetworkStatus();

        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
    }

    void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
    {
        PrintNetworkStatus();
    }

    private void PrintNetworkStatus()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        MessageBox.Show(NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType +
                        Environment.NewLine +
                        NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()));
    }
```

When I test this code snippet on my WP8 Lumia 920 it works as expected. On startup when my phone is on WiFi only I see the following MessageBox:

[image: Connected Messagebox]

And once I shutdown my WiFI router and the WiFi connection on the phone is lost I see the following MessageBox:

[image: Disconnected MessageBox]

Comment: I tried that, It works on WP8 project but doesn't work on Mvvm light projects

Comment: I'm unclear what an "MVVM Light project" is. AFAIK it's just a derivation of the original project template. Maybe it's best if you start from a WP8 New Project and add whatever 3rd party components and architecture you need to that project.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
bool isNetwork=NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if(!isNetwork)
{
   //proceed with your code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In App.xaml.cs, create a property like below

```
/// <summary>
/// check if network is available
/// </summary>
public bool IsNetworkAvailable
{
    get
    {
        return NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.None;
    }
}
```

And you can use this property anywhere in your project as in below code

```
if (((App) Application.Current).IsNetworkAvailable)
{
         //Lines of Code
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Not Connected to Network!", "Checking Connection!",
               MessageBoxButton.OK);     
}
```