# Check internet Connection on phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I wanted to check whether my phone can connect to Internet or not. I have seen several questions already. One of those is [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617017/windows-phone-8-connection-handler-internet-availability) . It says to use `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` this and i tried it. I have disconnected my PC from internet and Also turned off the `DataConnection` of the emulator but `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` this always returning true. But simultaneouly i also check for `NetworkInterfaceType.None` and interestingly it is coming null.
Can anybody explain where i am missing info ?

**Attempt** : -

```
public static void CheckNetworkAvailability()
    {
       // this is coming true even when i disconnected my pc from internet.
       // i also make the dataconnection off of the emulator
        var fg = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

        var ni = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
        // this part is coming none  
        if (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.None)
            IsConnected = false;

    }
```

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Will you be using the Internet in general, or are you checking if you can connect to the backend server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emulator always returns `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` as true, even if you emulate network conditions as having no network.

I faced this problem myself and the only truly way of testing this behaviour is to deploy the application to a physical device running Windows Phone and test it with the data turned off.

Comment: Is the ans below is right ?. I wanted to check for whether my app can connect to `internet` or not. nothing else.Like you said you have come across so how do you solve it ?

Comment: In windows phone, usually when a device is not connected to the internet, it is also not connected to a network. So I didn't bother going further than that.

Comment: I don't have device with me yet, have you tested it through cases ?

Answer (score 9):

I am using following code to check if the device has access to internet with if it is connected to wifi or data connection..

```
 public void UpdateNetworkInformation()
    {
        // Get current Internet Connection Profile.
        ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        //air plan mode is on...
        if (internetConnectionProfile == null)
        {
            Is_Connected = false;
            return;
        }

        //if true, internet is accessible.
        this.Is_InternetAvailable = internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;

        // Check the connection details.
        else if (internetConnectionProfile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType != 71)// Connection is not a Wi-Fi connection. 
        {
            Is_Roaming = internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming;

            /// user is Low on Data package only send low data.
            Is_LowOnData = internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().ApproachingDataLimit;

            //User is over limit do not send data
            Is_OverDataLimit = internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().OverDataLimit;

        }
        else //Connection is a Wi-Fi connection. Data restrictions are not necessary. 
        {
            Is_Wifi_Connected = true;
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
And for simple internet connection you can use below code.

```
  System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` checks the `network connection` and not the  `internet connection`. If you are in any kind of network, then it will return `true` whether `internet` is present or not.

You can check the internet connection as following:

```
using System.Net

private bool IsOnline() 
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry iPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.wikipedia.com");
        return true;
    }
    catch (SocketException ex) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```